# How to use parallel streaming safely in java?

Tags: java, parallel-processing

I am using parallel streams on a big calculation, but the results were strange when I executed it. When doing everything in pure `[SEQ]`-process-scheduling, it just works fine.

To find the problem I use a simple calculation ( The job is to add all natural numbers from 'iterations' to zero together ):

```
private long sum = 0;                  // global helper

public static void main(String args[])
{
    int iterations = 50000;            // the target number

    // solving the task parallel
    // ---------------------------------- <Section-under-Test>.START
    final long    startPAR =     System.nanoTime();
    IntStream.range(1, iterations+1).parallel().forEach(i->{

        sum += i;
    });
    final long durationPAR = ( ( System.nanoTime() - startPAR ) / 1_000_000 );
    // ---------------------------------- <Section-under-Test>.FINISH
    long sumParallel = sum; sum = 0;   // save + reset variable

    System.out.println( "Sum parallel: "  + sumParallel
                      + "         TOOK: " + durationPAR
                        );

    // solving the task linear using one core
    // ---------------------------------- <Section-under-Test>.START
    final long    startSEQ =     System.nanoTime();

    for(int i = 1; i < iterations+1; i++)
    {
        sum += i;
    }
    final long durationSEQ = ( ( System.nanoTime() - startSEQ ) / 1_000_000 );
    // ---------------------------------- <Section-under-Test>.FINISH

    System.out.println( "Sum serial:   "  + sum
                      + "         TOOK: " + durationSEQ
                        );
    System.out.println((sum == sumParallel));
}
```

Strangely I get different outputs each time I execute the parallel part:

```
Sum parallel: 354519954
Sum serial:  1250025000
false
---------------------------
Sum parallel: 453345292
Sum serial:  1250025000
false
---------------------------
Sum parallel: 613823840
Sum serial:  1250025000
false
```

## So what I want to know is:

- Why is this happening?
- And how to prevent this?

Did I miss the point and wanted to use the parallel computing in a wrong place?

### Info:

In my bigger calculation, I am calculating parallel that value to add to, in this case, the sum. So that works just fine. But how do I properly add this result to a global variable?

Comment: **Would you mind to kindly add measured durations ( using `System.nanoTime()` ) for each of the test runs?** It is significant to measure not only the result correctness, but also the **costs of using** the **`[SEQ]`** v/s **`[PAR]`** ( as implemented by `.parallel()` stream-methods ) process-scheduling strategies. The difference in one has surprised you already, but not reading the second is even a worse sin in the professional software engineering design practice. Would you be so kind to re-run the tests with timing + post the resulting `[SEQ]` & `[PAR]` duration times? **THANKS.**

Comment: @user3666197 sure, that was the second thing for me to do. It actually turned out to be significantly faster (12 seconds vs. 7 seconds) when doing it SEQ compared to PAR.

Comment: Would you mind to re-run the above updated code ( where measurements were already added, not the `.sum()` or the `.reduce()` methods, as even the "wrong" `[PAR]`-results may actually cost way more than a pure `[SEQ]`-processing ) and post the updated exact figures together with the number of your CPU-cores you execute on ( may try even to add a few warm-up + many measurement rounds, so as to filter some system-execution noise, but **hard facts matter so as to see the whole picture sharp and sound, right?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `sum += i;` is not atomic, it involves multiple operations:

1. Read `i`
2. Read `sum`
3. Compute `sum` plus `i`
4. Assign result to `sum`

At any point during the execution of those operations, we have other threads performing the same operations. If two threads read `sum` (operation 2) at the same time, you're guaranteed to get different results because when they both calculate `sum + i`, neither thread is taking the other's addition into consideration.

If you wanted to do such a calculation in parallel, use [**`AtomicLong`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html) instead. Operations such as `addAndGet` are guaranteed to be atomic, that is, it's guaranteed to occur in one step and not be broken up into the above steps.

Comment: Very neat, thank you. Another little question: Is there something like an AtomicDouble?

Comment: For your use-case, [`DoubleAdder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/DoubleAdder.html) seems like a good solution.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the **`.sum()`** method, so that no thread operates on a shared state, hence no need for synchronized or atomic access:

```
int sum = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, iterations).parallel().sum();
```

If you need more control over the calculation, you can use a **`.reduce()`** method:

```
int sum = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, iterations).parallel().reduce(0, (a, b) -> a + b);
```